# mousemove and mouseenter smooth scrolling left and right and mouseleave function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to make this animation scroll left and right more smoothly it uses $.throttle class which executes every millisecond it from github does anyone know of another approach for better smothness going left and right [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkbP6/182/) i also wanted to do a mouseleave and mouseout out of the wrapper to animate the scroll-content back to 0px  pixels how do i do that? my attempts have failed

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="scroll-content">
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/09f" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/2f2" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/234" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/342" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/312" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/131" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/111" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/222" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/333" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/122" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 170px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;
}
#scroll-content {
width: 1050px;
}
.item {
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    content = $('#scroll-content');

wrapper.bind('mouseenter mousemove', $.throttle(200, mousemove));

function mousemove(e) {
    var wrapper_width = wrapper.outerWidth(),
        content_width = content.outerWidth(),
        limits = 50,
        center = wrapper_width / 2,
        wrapper_pos = wrapper.offset(),
        mousePos = Math.min(Math.max(e.pageX,wrapper_pos.left + limits), wrapper_pos.left+wrapper_width-limits);

    //calculate new left margin
    var tmp
    if(e.pageX > center) {
    tmp = (mousePos + 50 - 5) * (content_width - wrapper_width) / wrapper_width;
}else{
         tmp = (mousePos - 50) * (content_width - wrapper_width) / wrapper_width;

        }

    content.stop().animate({
        'margin-left': '-' + tmp + 'px'
    }, 'fast', 'easeOutSine');
}
});
```

Comment: you know if you add another `li` it will not show ? it is expected ?

Comment: You could just decrease the `200` value, I think.

Comment: you just change the size of the scroll-content div

Answer (score 0):

I feel better using scroll left animation :

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        content = $('#scroll-content'),
        width=0.
        wrapper_width=wrapper.outerWidth(),
        w_half=wrapper_width/2;
    var w_left=wrapper.position().left;
    //FIXME wait for images load, to get  width or calculate width other way!
    
    //calculate inner width;
    $('#scroll-content .item').each(function() {
        width+=$(this).width()+5;
    });
    content.css('width',width);
    //
    
    content_width = content.outerWidth();
    wrapper.bind('mouseenter mousemove drag', mousemove);
    function mousemove(e) {
        var mouse_pos=e.pageX-w_left;
        var content_pos=mouse_pos/wrapper_width*content_width-w_half;
        //console.log(e);
        wrapper.stop();
        wrapper.animate({scrollLeft: content_pos},300);
            
    }
});
```

​

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LZ7Eq/)

may be some browsers do not like scrollposition not int or out of range, but I sure you can fix it yourself

Comment: Thanks for you're reply you're sample works well. Each element is going to be the same size inside scroll-content i added an if statement in my example dividing the elements width / 2(.item class) which is 50 so when you mouseover and mousemove there is limit to the right and left of 50 pixels which is a boundary can you recode what i've done please so it works properly with you're example

Comment: I just added boundary to test if it handle widget correct when it not on left side of the screen. You want me to edit answer ? You can edit answer and I will assept it if agree

Comment: I not understand about devide by 2 idea, how it should feel like ?

Comment: what i think about, is that calculate animation speed based on user behaviour, for example he trying to move mouse slower, to precision hit the image, but i not got how to calculate formula, i tried simple, and it just make everything jumping